# Getting Invalid Chai property: status error which was working fine

Tags: javascript, json, api, mocha.js, chai

would need bit of help. I have written a code for API Test which is below, but I am getting an error ***Invalid Chai property: status***. Can anyone of you please guide what am I doing wrong. This was working fine till few hours before.

Api is working fine too I have tallied by doing it manually.

```
import supertest from "supertest";
var chai = require('chai');
import { expect } from 'chai';
chai.use(require('chai-json-schema'));

const request = 
    supertest("https://graana.rocks/api/");

describe('Area_Details', () => {
    it('GET /areadetails', (done) => {
        process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
        request.get('area/1921').end((err,res) => {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            let array1 = Object.entries(res.body);
            expect(array1).to.be.a('array');
            expect(res.body).to.be.jsonSchema(CheckSchema);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `chai-http` plugin to be able to do:

```
expect(res).to.have.status(200);
```

Reference: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/

Comment: Can you please guide that how was it working prior to this :(

Answer (score 0):

From the doc [chai-http](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/)

> The Chai HTTP module provides a number of assertions for the expect and should interfaces.

`.status (code)` assertion is one of them.

`supertest` will **not** provide these assertions for the `expect` and `should` interfaces of chai.

See [chai-http/blob/4.3.0/lib/http.js#L79](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/blob/4.3.0/lib/http.js#L79)

```js
 Assertion.addMethod('status', function (code) {
    var hasStatus = Boolean('status' in this._obj || 'statusCode' in this._obj);
    new Assertion(hasStatus).assert(
        hasStatus
        , "expected #{act} to have keys 'status', or 'statusCode'"
        , null // never negated
        , hasStatus // expected
        , this._obj // actual
        , false // no diff
    );

    var status = this._obj.status || this._obj.statusCode;

    this.assert(
        status == code
      , 'expected #{this} to have status code #{exp} but got #{act}'
      , 'expected #{this} to not have status code #{act}'
      , code
      , status
    );
  });
```